# Передача массива по AJAX из PHP. Получаю данные, но не могу вывести чистый код PHP/HTML

Tags: php, ajax

Проблема в том, что мне нужно вывести из PHP файла данные с разметкой HTML, а здесь он передается в Json.

А мне нужно вывести такие данные к примеру:

```
<?php
    echo $d['seven']; 
    echo $d['eight']; 
    echo $d['nine']; 

?>
```

Как это сделать? Желательно максимально упрощенный вариант. Большое спасибо за помощь.

Вот пример работающего кода, но не передающего данные в нужном формате.

```
 <form method="post" id="ajax_form" action="" >
            <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="year"  /><br>
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="Send" />
        </form>
    
        <br>
    
        <div id="result_form"></div>
```

Передаем данные.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(
        function(){
            sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form', 'handler.php');
            return false; 
        }
    );
});
 





function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:     "POST", //метод отправки
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
        success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
            result = $.parseJSON(response);
            $('#result_form').html('Name: '+result.name+'<br>Year: '+result.phonenumber);
        },
        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
            $('#result_form').html('Error');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Исполняем.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["year"]) ) { 

    // Формируем массив для JSON ответа
    $result = array(
        'name' => $_POST["name"],
        'phonenumber' => $_POST["year"]
    ); 

    // Переводим массив в JSON
    echo json_encode($result); 
}



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работающий пример.

В форме переставьте значения полей namе и сами поля на те, что вам нужны и все.

****/* Страница к примеру index.php*/****

```
<form action="path/to/server/script" method="post" id="my_form">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="url" name="website" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
<div id="server-results"><!-- For server results --></div>
</form>
```

****/* Все таже страница index.php*/****

```
  <script>
$("#my_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
    
    $.ajax({
        url : 'handler.php',
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ //
        $("#server-results").html(response);
    });
});
   
   </script>
```

*** Файл /* handler.php */ в котором вы делаете со своими переменными что вам нужно. Для примера, я их просто вывел в echo***

```
 <?php 
    
    /* Handler */
         Подключаем базу данных из вашего сайта, если это необходимо.
    
    
    if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["website"])) { 
    
      
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $website = $_POST['website'];
    
     /* Здесь формируйте результаты как вы этого хотите, включая html код*/ 
    
           echo $name . $email . $website;
    
    }
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема в том, что мне нужно вывести

Нет, проблема в том, что Вы не сказали, чем Вас не устраивает приведенный код.

---

Как сочетаются эти две строчки? -

```
dataType: "html", //формат данных

...

echo json_encode($result);
```

---

```
dataType: "json",
...

  //result = $.parseJSON(response);
  $('#result_form').html('Name: ' + response.name + '<br>Year: ' + response.phonenumber);
```

Comment: Мне необходимо из файла PHP выводить данные не через Json а через Echo, даже если их будет 10 штук.    То есть надо заменить echo json_encode($result);    на echo html($result);  ?????? То есть что в PHP поставили на вывод через echo то и вывелось в  <div id="result_form"></div>

Comment: @Liza "выводить данные не через Json а через Echo" - Почему?

Comment: Выстроить дизайн массива, который будет передаваться в результаты полученных данных. Это поисковая форма состоящая из 2-х значений.